# Get "Unauthoirzed" error when both run this project and call the same request on postman

Tags: azure, api, error-handling, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working with a project that our backend need to use an outlook admin acount that whenever recieve a new mail from user, my backend will handle some process. After some researching , I found that I need to use Microsoft Graph API with Client Credential grant. Folowing your step, after getting access token, I use it to signup subscription, unfortunately I got this Error :

> "error": { "code": "ExtensionError", "message": " Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Unauthorized; reason: The Tenant for Tenent guid {id} does not exist.]",

It took me about one week and I still Stuck at here, It strongly influence on my project of my company. please help me if you could solve this, thanks !

[image]

Comment: How did you get the access token?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, after getting access token successfully , I used It to signup subscription and got this Error.

Comment: Can you paste the request url and params here? The way to get access token.

Comment: Yes.  I use Method GET to this url https://login.microsoftonline.com/{MyTenentId}/oauth2/v2.0/token
The params are { "grant_type": "client_credential", "client_id": {MyClientId}, "scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", "client_secret" : {MyClientSecret} }

Comment: Sorry very much for late response

Comment: You must use `POST` method for this token request

Comment: Both using POST and GET method return a access Token, but still return the same Error when use those token @@

Comment: @khanhnguyen Please share your token request format

Comment: Yes the Url is: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{MytenentID}/oauth2/v2.0/token

params: { "grant_type":"client_credentials","client_id":{MyClientId},"scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", "client_secret": {MyClientSecret} }